# drand48 returning all 0's? (C)

Tags: c, matrix

Trying to make a matrix of n size with all random numbers using drand48, but it only returns 0's and for some reason the compiler is giving me a warning that drand is returning ints when the man page clearly states it should be a double, can someone please tell me what im doing wrong? function is called like `./matrix 4` where the 2nd arg is n for a nxn matrix, im developing on mint linux

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int matrixSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("matrixsize %d\n", matrixSize);

    //create matrix of n size 
    int mat[matrixSize][matrixSize],i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < matrixSize ; ++j){
            mat[i][j] = drand48();
            printf("%f\n", mat[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `drand48` does return doubles. The problem is you are storing the result into an array of `int`s. From the documentation of `drand48`:

> The drand48() and erand48() functions return non-negative, double-precision, floating-point values, uniformly distributed over the interval [0.0 , 1.0].

Since your code declares a 2-dimensional array of `int`s, all results of `drand48()` are truncated to 0 since the function returns values from 0-1.

Change the array declaration to:

```
//create matrix of n size 
double mat[matrixSize][matrixSize],i,j;
```

Comment: You also should seed your RNG if you don't want the exact some results every time you run your program.  Add "srand48(time(NULL))" below your print statement.